# How can I use a 3d array as a datasource for a UICollectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, uicollectionview

I have a datasource that is a three dimensional array.

I am using the first dimension count as the number of sections.

I am using the third dimension as the items in each section.

Here is some sample data:

```
let sentence1 = [word1, word2, word1] // These are Word objects
let sentence2 = [word1, word2, word3] // in my model.
let sentence3 = [word4, word5, word3]

let paragraph1 = [sentence1, sentence2] // These are Sentence objects.
let paragraph2 = [sentence1, sentence3]

let article = [paragraph1, paragraph2]
```

Currently I have just made a copy of 3dArray and flattened the second and third dimension into one dimension thus making the three dimensional array into a two dimensional array. I am then returning new2dArray.count as the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and making cells, in cellForItemAtIndexPath, with something like this:

```
let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

let cellLabel = new2dArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

However, in my didSelectItemAtIndexPath I need access to the 2nd dimension of 3dArray. I am looking for something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("did select cell \(indexPath.row) inside of \(secondDimension) inside of \(indexPath.section)")
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Why not try an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a section, and inside the dictionary you can store an array representing the rows in that section?

Comment: That may work, but i need the sections to be in order. Is there a way to ensure that the sections are in order if I use a dictionary?

Comment: The array will maintain the order for you, so it is an array of dictionaries. And within each dictionary you have key-value pair for the rowData and another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:

1. Partially flatten the 3d array to become a 2d array useable as a datasource for the collection view.
2. Find what the index of the twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] would be if that array were also flattened. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28742108/538034)
3. Count that many elements in the threeDimensionalArray and then save the individual indexes like this:

   ```
   func find3dIndex(article: Array<Array<Array<String>>>, flatWordIndex: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
           var fullSentenceArray = [String]()
           var counter = 0

           for index in 0...flatWordIndex {
               for (paragraphIndex, paragraph) in enumerate(article) {
                   for (sentenceIndex, sentence) in enumerate(paragraph) {
                       for (wordIndex,word) in enumerate(sentence) {
                           if counter == flatWordIndex {
                               println("tuple: \(paragraphIndex), \(sentenceIndex), \(wordIndex)")    
                               return (paragraphIndex, sentenceIndex, wordIndex)    
                               break
                           }
                           counter += 1
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       return (99,99,99)
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, why not try an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a section, and inside the dictionary you can store an array representing the rows in that section. Here is some pseudocode:

```
// The items in the array under 'kRowData' represent each individual cell, this maybe a value, a model object, or even another dictionary
let sectionOne = ["kRowData" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
let sectionTwo = ["kRowData" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
let sectionThree = ["kRowData" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]]

let sectionData = [sectionOne,sectionTwo,sectionThree]

sectionData.count // your number of sections
sectionData[indexPath.section]["kRowData"].count // your number of rows in section
```

Comment: This is looking interesting (in a good way). Let me consider this for a while. Thank you.

Comment: Some of my cells have the same content as other cells within the same dimension. Wouldn't that be a problem when using a dictionary?

Comment: Not sure I understand? Each entry in your kRowData array will represent a cell, and will store a reference to some model object/dictionary/value, if two cells share the same data the same reference will be stored twice in the array. Could you give an example?

Comment: First dimension is paragraphs, second dimension is sentences, third dimension is array of words. Some words will be repeated in a normal sentence.

Comment: Not sure why that isn't accomplishable with a dictionary?

Comment: You are probably right, but I am considering the fact that each dictionary key has to be unique.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of some data for 2 sections and a few rows? Because in my implementation, you would store a model object/another dictionary/or value in an array to represent all the rows in a particular section

Comment: Added some sample data. Thanks for sticking with me on this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: How do sentences, words and paragraphs relate to sections and rows?

Comment: In my case a paragraph is a section and the words are cells. Words have properties like definition and pronunciation. I need each word to know which sentence it is in.