# How can I tell what the index of an item in a multidimensional array would be if the array were flattened?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with some repeated elements in the deepest level:

```
[
    ["taco","burrito"],
    ["chalupa","taco","bread"]
    ["pizza","lasagna"],
    ["pizza","taco","burrito"]
    ["salad","sandwich"],
    ["meat","turkey"]
    ["cups","chicken"],
    ["rabbit","taco", "chicken", "salad"]
]
```

I have flattened this array into...

```
[
    "taco",
    "burrito",
    "chalupa",
    "taco",
    "bread",
    "pizza",
    "lasagna",
    etc...
]
```

I have found the second occurrence of the word "taco" in the multidimensional array and know its index.

How can I translate that index to an index in the flattened array?

So in this example it would be...

```
multiDimensionalArray[0][1][1]

=

flatArray[3]
```

Comment: Maybe it's your formatting, but wouldn't array[0][0][1] give you `["chalupa","taco"]`?

Comment: Is there a reason "flatten the array and search for the second 'taco'" isn't the answer you're looking for?

Comment: I am not sure, but I am thinking that won't work for my needs.

Comment: Oh, I realize why.  It is because I won't know that that "taco" is the second taco. I will only know its indexes.

Comment: What you have here is two separate arrays. Is there a missing comma? Also, is this supposed to be two or three dimensional? Also, why not use objects?

Comment: @webmagnets I think you have put additional ][ in. The two in the middle shouldn't be there I think.

Comment: I think you are right. I was also missing a comma. See if it looks right now.

Comment: OK, cool :D Wasn't sure which was the incorrect bit :D

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't really matter. The main question is what I want an answer to.

Comment: So, in this multi dimensional array the index of the second string "taco" is `array[0][0][1][1]` is that what you want to get? Or do you want to get `3` as in it is the fourth word so index = 3? Not sure what you are wanting to find?

Comment: I want to convert a multidimensional index to a flattened index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71704/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-webmagnets).

Comment: @webmagnets I have edited your question. Please check that it is correct. Thanks

Comment: Close, but in reverse.

Comment: Surely can you not just iterate the flat array to find the second occurrence again? That would be easier than finding it in the multi-dimensional array in the first place.

Comment: This is the datasource for a uicollectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath, so I only know the string and the index section and row. I don't know that it is the second taco. I am trying to use a 3d array and use 2d of it to make the collection view. Does that make sense?

Comment: So each item is "taco", "burrito", etc...?

Comment: yes, the elements are strings.

Comment: @webmagnets going bac to chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
func findFlattenedIndex(array: Array<Array<String>>, firstIndex: Int, secondIndex: Int) -> Int {

    var flatIndex = 0

    for (index1,secondTier) in enumerate(array) {
        for element in secondTier {
                if index1 != firstIndex{
                    println(element)
                    flatIndex += 1
                }
        }
        if index1 == firstIndex {
            flatIndex += secondIndex
            return flatIndex
            break
        }
    }
    return flatIndex
}
```

Of course this could be modified to deal with any number of dimensions.

Thanks for everyone's help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't have native support for flattening arrays. You could roll this out yourself, or you could use [ExSwift](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift) which has a flatten method. If you flatten the array successfully, obviously you could then determine which index the value is at using [indexOfObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:). Since you have multiple identical objects, you may want to use [indexesOfObjectsPassingTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:), which will give you an index set for all indexes matching the test you provide.

Comment: Well, I need that specific element; not a list of all the indexes matching the test.

Comment: Once you have the index, you can get that element from the flattened array, right? NSString `var elementString = flatArray[index]`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Check out this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71704/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-webmagnets

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a function to flatten the array into an array of strings in order to gain the true indices of the elements.

```
public func flattenArray(array: Array<AnyObject>) -> Array<String> {
    var flattened: Array<String> = []
    for object: AnyObject in array {
        if object is Array<AnyObject> {
            for string in flattenArray(object as Array<AnyObject>) {
                flattened.append(string)
            }
        } else if object is String {
            flattened.append(object as String)
        }
    }
    return flattened
}
```

---

Then you need to write a function that will obtain the index of an element in an array at a certain number of occurrences

```
public func indexOfString(string: String, inArray array: Array<String>, occurance: Int = 1) -> Int? {

    var occurancesSoFar = 0
    var index: Int? = nil
    var currentIndex = 0

    for object in array {
        if object == string {
            if (++occurancesSoFar == occurance) {
                index = currentIndex
            }
        }
        ++currentIndex
    }

    return index
}
```

---

Calling the above functions in order gives the correct index value:

```
let array = [
    ["taco","burrito"],
    ["chalupa","taco","bread"],
    ["pizza","lasagna"],
    ["pizza","taco","burrito"],
    ["salad","sandwich"],
    ["meat","turkey"],
    ["cups","chicken"],
    ["rabbit","taco", "chicken", "salad"]
]

let flat = flattenArray(array)

let index = indexOfString("taco", inArray: flat, occurance: 2)
println(index) // Optional(3)
```

---

Using these methods you could encapsulate them into a single function perhaps called

```
func flattenAndFindElement(element: String, 
                           inArray array: Array<AnyObject>, 
                           atOccurrence occurrence: Int) -> Int?
```

or something similar.

Hope that helps answer your question.